# Consider $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. find k such that $P(k)>\frac{4}{5}$

Tags: probability

Consider $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. And also suppose $P(x)=${probability such that all member of "$A$" have been chosen after that one person choose  member of $A$ randomly $x$ times  }.

Find $K$ such that $P(K)>\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: In other words, "how many random draws from an uniform distribution with $5$ outcomes must one make before the probability that each outcome has occurred at least once is at least $\frac45$"? Prose would be much clearer here than trying (mostly unsuccessfully) to cram it into symbols.

Comment: Note that this probability can be calculated as follows: $P(x) = \frac{\#V}{\#\Omega}$  where $\Omega$ is the set of all functions from a set of $x$ elements to $A$ and $V$ is the set of those functions that are surjections. A link to the values of $\#V$ is [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=120%2C1800%2C16800%2C126000&sort=&language=english&go=Search).